# Trying to generate a random letter error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char' in assignment

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the char. How do I convert the string to char? I get this error:

> error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char' in assignment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int const MAX = 4;

string randomString(int n){// generating random letter

    char alphabet[MAX] = { 'r', 'a', 'n', 'd'};

    string res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res = res + alphabet[rand() % MAX];
 
    return res;
}

int main (){
    srand(time(NULL));
    char random;

    random = randomString(1);// problem lies here
    char a1 = random;

    char a2 = random;

    char a3 = random;
    cout<<a1<< " " << a2 << " " << a3<< endl;
}
```

Comment: `randomString` returns a `std::string`, `random` is a `char`.

Comment: `std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}` just means "`std::string`".  Your error is "`cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char' in assignment`".  Which is true. A `std::string` has no implicit conversion to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to think that `random` is an alias for `randomString(1)` and that assigning `random` to multiple variables will call `randomString(1)` multiple times. It does not. That is not how variables work.

You are calling `randomString(1)` one time and then trying to assign its return value, which is a `std::string` (ie a collection of `char`s), to a  single `char`. No such conversion exists, hence the error.

Try this instead:

```cpp
int main (){
    srand(time(NULL));
    string a1 = randomString(1);
    string a2 = randomString(1);
    string a3 = randomString(1);
    cout << a1 << " " << a2 << " " << a3 << endl;
}
```

If you really want single `char`s, use `std::string::operator[]`:

```cpp
int main (){
    srand(time(NULL));
    char a1 = randomString(1)[0];
    char a2 = randomString(1)[0];
    char a3 = randomString(1)[0];
    cout << a1 << " " << a2 << " " << a3 << endl;
}
```